# Exclusionary Left Joins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, join

I'm trying to join 2 different tables (Table99 and Table2) to Table1.  The first is a straight-forward RIGHT JOIN.  The second is a LEFT JOIN, where I'm trying to take Table1 and Left Join to a Table2, and bring back results from Table1 that don't exist in Table2

Example:

```
 FROM Table1 tbl1 
      RIGHT JOIN Table99 tbl99 ON tbl1.CARD_ID = tbl99.CARD_ID 
            AND tbl1.DATE_OPEN = tbl99.DATE_OPEN 

      LEFT JOIN Table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = tbl2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
           AND tbl1.APPL_ID = tbl2.APPL_ID'

WHERE tbl1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER <> tbl2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
```

The Left Join clause is where I'm trying to pull in all of the results from tble1 that do NOT exist in tbl2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> bring back results from Table1 that don't exist in Table2

You can use [NOT EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT
    T1.*
FROM
    TABLE1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM   TABLE2 T2
                 WHERE  T2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = T1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
                        AND T2.APPL_ID = T1.APPL_ID );
```

**Update**

It doesn't matter how many JOIN's you use before the [left anti semi join](https://sqlity.net/en/1360/a-join-a-day-the-left-anti-semi-join/), it returns all rows from the left side that does not exists on the right side, according the predicate: `WHERE T2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = T1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AND  T2.APPL_ID = T1.APPL_ID`

```
SELECT
    T1.*
FROM
    TABLE1 T1
RIGHT JOIN 
    TABLE99 T99
    ON T99.CARD_ID = T99.CARD_ID 
    AND T99.DATE_OPEN = T1.DATE_OPEN
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM   TABLE2 T2
                 WHERE  T2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = T1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
                        AND  T2.APPL_ID = T1.APPL_ID
                );
```

Let's imagine 3 tables with next ID's:

```
 T1    T2    T9
----  ----  ----
 01    01    01
 02          02
 03    03
 04    04    04
 05          05
```

Give me all ID's that exists in T1 and T9.

```
SELECT ID FROM T1 JOIN T9 ON T1.ID = T2.ID;

01,02,04,05
```

and now, give me all ID's of this group that does not exists in T2:

<sub>pseudo-code:</sub>

```
SELECT ID FROM (01,02,04,05) WHERE NOT EXISTS IN (01,03,04);

02,05
```

**NOTE**: I've replaced table names by their values to make the final result more clear

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your where clause.

AND tbl2.APPL_ID IS NULL

Comment: This does not seem like the best way to do that.

Comment: But it will work, and it is simple, maintainable, and deterministic.